# Turning a private struct hasher operator into static

Tags: c++

I have implemented a class `A` which holds an `unordered_set` of class `B` instances, using a custom hasher function.

File `a.hh`:

```
#include "b.hh"

class A {

private:
  struct HashB_ {
    size_t operator()( const B & ) const ;
  };

  typedef std::unordered_set< B, A::HashB_ > HashTable_t_ ;

  HashTable_t_ hash_table_;
};
```

File `a.cpp`:

```
#include "a.hh"

size_t
A::HashB_::operator()( const B & b ) const {
  return b.getHash();
}
```

Where `b.getHash()` implements the actual hashing.

My **goal** is to make this private hasher function **static**, if possible, as it does not interact at all with the members of class `A`. Defining the hasher outside of class `A` would be an alternative, but I wish to hide the implementation outside of class `A`.

If I try to declare `static size_t operator()( const B & );` I get the following compilation error: `must be a nonstatic member function`.

And if I declare `static struct HashB_` I get the following error: `a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions`.

Is it possible do turn this private hasher into a private "static" hasher? And would it make any sense in doing so? Or should I do it with a `friend` hasher, instead, to hide the implementation?

Comment: Good news: you've already accomplished your goal. The hasher function, despite being a non-static member function cannot "interact al all" with the members of class A. An instance of an inner class is not a member of an outer class, hence it has no access to any member of any instance of the outer class (unless it finds a pointer to an instance, somewhere, or something along those lines). What you are thinking about is how Java implements inner classes. But this is C++, not Java.

Comment: It could use other members of `HashB_`, but there are none.

Comment: I would try `static size_t HashB_(const B &b) { ... }` for you (to see if it could work), but your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The function call operator does require an object to work on even if they don't need to touch the object. That's a deliberate choice to establish the relevant context for looking up the function call operator. That operator can't be `static`.

You *could* use a `static` function in your class `A`. However, the unordered containers use an object to specify the hashing operation. A function pointer to the `static` member is a suitable object. However, you'd need to use a function pointer type for the hasher template argument and pass the function pointer to the constructor of the unordered cintainer. Aside to this syntactic complication this approach probably has a negative performance impact: conpilers are really good at inlining member functions which do not touch any if the member. They do have a hard time doing the appropriate analysis with function pointers, even in simple looking cases.

tl;dr: don't worry about the hash object not having any member and the function call operator being non-`static`: it is likely the most effective approach!